# Facebook Open Graph posting on my profile timeline is not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to integrate open graph in my website, so that I can post a link to my profile page and it will display the relevant information (title, description etc).

Yet, even though it worked for some time, and not worked most of the times for other users.

My website: http://www.yambo.com

The test page: http://www.yambo.com/me/yambosite/video/297403960901

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that other users do not have the timeline option enabled on their profiles which would mean that you can't post those types of notifications.